# Audio Recorder app in kotlin is crashing when I click on start record button

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, audio-streaming

I am creating an audio recorder app in kotlin, I followed a video in youtube ([video Link tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z0AZoTxWYQ&t=894s)) and finally his app working fine but my app is crashing when I click on start/stop/play button when it is enabled (code is same).
What I tried: I created a simple toast button and when click on it, it shows the text (app is not crashing)
Can you please help what could be the problem
Thanks in advance.

My android studio version: android studio arctic fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Sdk platforms: android 11.0 (R) API Level 30

MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.example.recordaudiodemo

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mr : MediaRecorder

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button4 : Button = findViewById(R.id.button4)
        val button5 : Button = findViewById(R.id.button5)
        val button6 : Button = findViewById(R.id.button6)
        val buttonT : Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonT)

        var path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/myrec.3gp"
        mr = MediaRecorder()

        button4.isEnabled = false //start
        button5.isEnabled = false //stop

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 111)
            button4.isEnabled = true

        // start recording
        button4.setOnClickListener {
            mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
            mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            mr.setOutputFile(path)
            try {
                mr.prepare()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // handle error
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                // handle error
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
//            mr.prepare()
            mr.start()
            button5.isEnabled = true
            button4.isEnabled = false
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Start button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        // stop recording
        button5.setOnClickListener {
            mr.stop()
            button4.isEnabled = true
//            button5.isEnabled = false
        }

        // play recording
        button6.setOnClickListener {
            var mp = MediaPlayer()
            mp.setDataSource(path)
            mp.prepare()
            mp.start()
        }

        // Toast button
        buttonT.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Toast button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == 111 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            button4.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

build.gradle(app) file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.recordaudiodemo"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

AndroidManifest.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.recordaudiodemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RecordAudioDemo">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ActivityMain.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Record Audio App"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="STOP"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:text="START"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="PLAY"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="143dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="153dp"
        android:text="Toast Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: add stack trace so we can identify exact issue

Comment: You should run recording in IO thread.

Comment: Can you share the error you got?

Comment: I put breakpoint at start(), when the app crashes i got the following error: E/MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4,     
W/recordaudiodem: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void android.media.MediaRecorder.start()